# How do I fix "template is missing" in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I am using theme in Wordpress but it is giving error in **theme broken**:

> Template is missing

How can I fix it? I am using [this theme](http://themeforest.net/item/simplegreat-premium-responsive-opencart-theme/4792599).

This theme have these files and folders:

```
conf

core_files

css

fonts

images

img

js

lang

 **Files**

.gitignore

detail.php

head-css.php

main.php

mediamanager.php

README.markdown

sidebar.php

style.ini

tail-js.php

template.info.txt

tpl_functions.php
```

Comment: Ask the [Support Center](http://support.envato.com/) for their help.

Comment: This question may be off-topic because it outlines a highly localised situation that is unlikely to be of widespread interest to future readers.

Comment: Hi Ricky. I've voted to close, as this is a very unusual situation. However, it looks like two eagle-eyed readers have spotted the problem in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theme you are attempting to install is not a WordPress theme. It is a theme for OpenCart, a shopping cart module.

Comment: I am really sorry...Jack B... You are right

Comment: No worries Ricky, it's an easy mistake to make since Themeforest is largely WordPress themes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any other cms theme in wordpress. You can use only wordpress theme
in wordpress cms. I am looking that your theme is opencart theme that cannot be
used in wordpress cms.

Comment: Arshad, code formatting is not appropriate for ordinary paragraph text. I've removed it once already. Please write text without line breaks, as this makes it easier for future editors - text wraps automatically.